# upload image from local into tinyMCE

Tags: html, tinymce

**tinyMCE** has an insert image button, but how to handle its functionality
pls give some code

Comment: You need to buy the imagemanager component to enable this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Din't try iManager but found tinyFCK good and easy to configure which gives CKEditor's filemanager integrated with TinyMCE

1.Download [TinyFCK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p4a/files/tinyfck/0.16/tinyfck-0.16.tar.gz/download)

2.replace filemanger folder in tinyFCK with filemanager folder of ur CKEditor

3.code :

-

```
tinyMCE.init({
     theme : "advanced",
     file_browser_callback : "fileBrowserCallBack",
});
function fileBrowserCallBack(field_name, url, type, win) {
     var connector = "../../filemanager/browser.html?Connector=connectors/php/connector.php";
     var enableAutoTypeSelection = true;
     var cType;
     tinyfck_field = field_name;
     tinyfck = win;
     switch (type) {
         case "image":
             cType = "Image";
         break;
         case "flash":
             cType = "Flash";
         break;
         case "file":
             cType = "File";
         break;
     }
     if (enableAutoTypeSelection && cType) {
         connector += "?Type=" + cType;
     }
     window.open(connector, "tinyfck", "modal,width=600,height=400");
  }
```

Answer (score 29):

I have upvoted the code written by @pavanastechie, but I ended up rewriting it quite a lot. Here's a version that is far shorter, which might have value to some people

```
    tinymce.init({
        toolbar : "imageupload",
        setup: function(editor) {
            var inp = $('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
            $(editor.getElement()).parent().append(inp);

            inp.on("change",function(){
                var input = inp.get(0);
                var file = input.files[0];
                var fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = function() {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = fr.result;
                    editor.insertContent('<img src="'+img.src+'"/>');
                    inp.val('');
                }
                fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            });

            editor.addButton( 'imageupload', {
                text:"IMAGE",
                icon: false,
                onclick: function(e) {
                    inp.trigger('click');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

NOTE: this relies on jquery, and won't work without it. Also, it assumes that the browser supports `window.FileReader`, and doesn't check for it.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Helped me a ton!

Comment: Thanks a lot but may i know how can i specify the path where i want to upload the image

Comment: The image is saved inline, not as a separate file. Like `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />`

Comment: so what can be done as a solution? Can we upload the image on to the server in specific folder?

Comment: If you use this code, you are committed to the image being embedded in the html, not stored in the filesystem as a separate file. That is a solution to the original problem ("upload image from local into tinyMCE"). If you have a different problem, you might need a different solution.

Comment: TinyMCE already comes with similar functionality: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/upload-images/

Comment: Script works great except why you empty the inp.val()? I manage to upload by removing that.

Now I am working on multiple upload based on your script

Comment: image with filesize above 200kb not working in edit mode!! is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 15):

I used pavanastechie's and Chris Lear's solutions, which worked perfectly for me, and wanted to share a complete example built on theirs that uploads the image to the server and embeds the image using the URL provided back by the server:

```
tinymce.init({
  toolbar: 'imageupload',
  setup: function(editor) {
    initImageUpload(editor);
  }
});

function initImageUpload(editor) {
  // create input and insert in the DOM
  var inp = $('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
  $(editor.getElement()).parent().append(inp);

  // add the image upload button to the editor toolbar
  editor.addButton('imageupload', {
    text: '',
    icon: 'image',
    onclick: function(e) { // when toolbar button is clicked, open file select modal
      inp.trigger('click');
    }
  });

  // when a file is selected, upload it to the server
  inp.on("change", function(e){
    uploadFile($(this), editor);
  });
}

function uploadFile(inp, editor) {
  var input = inp.get(0);
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('image[file]', input.files[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: '/admin/images',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    processData: false, // Don't process the files
    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      editor.insertContent('<img class="content-img" src="' + data.url + '"/>');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if(jqXHR.responseText) {
        errors = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText).errors
        alert('Error uploading image: ' + errors.join(", ") + '. Make sure the file is an image and has extension jpg/jpeg/png.');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 11):

**!!!!ENJOY!!!**  **here is the solution to load directly from local computer**

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1ad17co9/)

`<textarea name="content"></textarea>
<title>Local image loading in to tinymce</title>
<br/>
<b>Image size should be lessthan 500kb</b>`

**JAVA SCRIPT CODE**

`

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    toolbar: "mybutton",
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
            text:"IMAGE",
            icon: false,
            onclick: function(e) {
                console.log($(e.target));
                if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'BUTTON'){
                    console.log($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input').attr('id'));
                    if($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input').attr('id') != 'tinymce-uploader') {
                        $(e.target).parent().parent().append('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
                    }
                    $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');
                    $('#tinymce-uploader').change(function(){
                        var input, file, fr, img;

                        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
                            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
                            return;
                        }

                        input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
                        if (!input) {
                            write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
                        } else if (!input.files) {
                            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
                        } else if (!input.files[0]) {
                            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
                        } else {
                            file = input.files[0];
                            fr = new FileReader();
                            fr.onload = createImage;
                            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }

                        function createImage() {
                            img = new Image();
                            img.src = fr.result;
                            editor.insertContent('<img src="'+img.src+'"/>');
                        }
                    });

                }

                if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'DIV'){
                    if($(e.target).parent().find('input').attr('id') != 'tinymce-uploader') {
                        console.log($(e.target).parent().find('input').attr('id'));                                
                        $(e.target).parent().append('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
                    }
                    $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');
                    $('#tinymce-uploader').change(function(){
                        var input, file, fr, img;

                        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
                            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
                            return;
                        }

                        input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
                        if (!input) {
                            write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
                        } else if (!input.files) {
                            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
                        } else if (!input.files[0]) {
                            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
                        } else {
                            file = input.files[0];
                            fr = new FileReader();
                            fr.onload = createImage;
                            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }

                        function createImage() {
                            img = new Image();
                            img.src = fr.result;
                             editor.insertContent('<img src="'+img.src+'"/>');
                        }
                    });
                }

                if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'I'){
                    console.log($(e.target).parent().parent().parent().find('input').attr('id')); if($(e.target).parent().parent().parent().find('input').attr('id') != 'tinymce-uploader') {               $(e.target).parent().parent().parent().append('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
                                                                                           }
                    $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');
                    $('#tinymce-uploader').change(function(){
                        var input, file, fr, img;

                        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
                            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
                            return;
                        }

                        input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
                        if (!input) {
                            write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
                        } else if (!input.files) {
                            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
                        } else if (!input.files[0]) {
                            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
                        } else {
                            file = input.files[0];
                            fr = new FileReader();
                            fr.onload = createImage;
                            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
                        }

                        function createImage() {
                            img = new Image();
                            img.src = fr.result;
                             editor.insertContent('<img src="'+img.src+'"/>');
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }
});
```

`

Comment: when i try this in my local machine i need to click outside the text "image" but inside the button so that the search will work.. y though?

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old, but maybe this will help someone trying to find a open source file manager for tinymce:

https://github.com/2b3ez/FileManager4TinyMCE

This worked great for me.

Comment: Hi can u provide some example? I got error "There is an error! The root folder not exist." when using this plugin :(

Comment: @dmh create `/var/ww/html/tinymce/source` folder and give apache write permission on it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Chris Lear's answer, I have re-modified the script so that it supports multiple file uploads to server, and removed the data image for preview after content is posted and before table is updated with a little php script

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        setup: function(editor) {
                var n = 0;
                var form = $('#form_id'); // your form id
                editor.addButton( 'imageupload', {
                        text:"IMAGE",
                        icon: false,
                        onclick: function(e) {
                            $(form).append('<input id="tinymce-uploader_'+n+'" class="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic['+n+']" mutliple accept="image/*" style="display: none;">');
                            $('#tinymce-uploader_'+n).trigger('click');
                            n++;
                            $('.tinymce-uploader').on("change",function(){
                                    var input = $(this).get(0);
                                    var file = input.files[0];
                                    var filename = file.name;
                                    var fr = new FileReader();
                                    fr.onload = function() {
                                            var img = new Image();
                                            img.src = fr.result;
                                            editor.insertContent('<img data-name="'+filename+'" src="'+img.src+'"/>');
                                    }
                                    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
                            });
                        }
                });
        },
```

And on php side inside the upload php file:

```
function data2src($content, $img_path ='') {
        preg_match('/data\-name="([^"]+)/i',$content, $data_name);
        $tmp = preg_replace('/src=["]data([^"]+)["]/i', '', $content);
        $content = preg_replace('/data\-name\=\"/i', 'src="'.$img_path, $tmp);
        return $content;        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question. However, I think this answer may help somebody who wants to upload multiple images by using tinyMCE 5.xx.
Based on @Chris Lear's and @stephen.hanson's answer, I modify some code to support multiple images uploading. Here is my code. Hope it could help somebody.

```
tinymce.init({
toolbar: 'imageupload',
setup: function(editor) {
  initImageUpload(editor);
  }
});

function initImageUpload(editor) {
// create input and insert in the DOM
 var inp = $(`<input id='tinymce-uploader' type='file' name='pic' accept='image/*' style='display:none' multiple>`);
  $(editor.getElement()).parent().append(inp);
// add the image upload button to the editor toolbar
  editor.addButton('imageupload', {
  text:'IMAGE',
  onAction: function(_) { 
 // when toolbar button is clicked, open file select modal
    inp.trigger('click');
  }
});
 // when a file is selected, upload it to the server
inp.on('change',function(){
    for(let i=0;i<inp[0].files.length;i++){
        let file = inp[0].files[i];
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('multipartFile',file);
        axios.post('/upload/image/url',
        data,
        {
         headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
         }).then(res => {
          if (res.status = 200) { 
              editor.insertContent('<img class="content-img" src="' + data.url + '"/>');
             // clear data to avoid uploading same data not working in the second time
             inp.val('');
          }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for image upload.Is this possible for file upload ? I want to add a custom file upload option  from local into tinyMCE and want to show it by url .

```
 Code is something like below which not working:


   ed.addButton('mybutton2', {
        text:"File",
        icon: false,

        onclick: function(e) {
            console.log($(e.target));
            if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'BUTTON'){
                console.log($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input').attr('id'));
                if($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input').attr('id') != 
'tinymce-uploader') {
                    $(e.target).parent().parent().append('<input id="tinymce- 
uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="*" height="100" weidth="100" 
 style="display:none">');
                }
                $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');
                $('#tinymce-uploader').change(function(){
                    var input, file, fr, img;

                    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
                        write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
                        return;
                    }

                    input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
                           // var URL = document.my_form.my_field.value;
       alert(input.files[0]);
                    if (!input) {
                        write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
                    } else if (!input.files) {
                        write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` 
              property of file inputs.");

                    } else if (!input.files[0]) {
                        write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
                       alert( input.files[0]);
                    } else {
                        file = input.files[0];
                        fr = new FileReader();
                        fr.onload = createFile;
                        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
                            //  alert(fr.result);

                    }

                    function createFile() {
                       //what should I write here?
                      ed.insertContent('<a href="'+img.src+'">download 
      file_name</a>');
                    }
                });

            }







        }
    });
```