# How to upload images in Spring MVC from TinyMCE editor

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, file-upload, tinymce

I am making a content management system for ecommerce and have a blocks which would be displayed in different parts of the pages. This blocks can contain html and images, so I use `<textarea>` with TinyMCE to manage blocks content.

I didn't found complete solution anywhere - only separate questions about TinyMCE or loading images controllers, so I want to share my experience with you - complete JavaScript for TinyMCE initialization and back end controller, that saves images.

JavaScript is taken from [this theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872009/upload-image-from-local-into-tinymce) answers(I used steve.hanson answer), but I changed it a bit to fit my controller and moved image button methods inside setup function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important thing- 'files' is the name of multipart form variable in ajax and controller, and request url is : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/a/images'

JavaScript initialization of TinyMCE and ajax request to process images:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script> 
<script>
tinymce.init({      
      selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
      auto_focus: 'element1',
      toolbar: 'undo redo | imageupload',
      setup: function(editor) {

              // create input and insert in the DOM
              var inp = $('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
              $(editor.getElement()).parent().append(inp);

              // add the image upload button to the editor toolbar
              editor.addButton('imageupload', {
                text: 'Add image',  
                icon: 'image',
                onclick: function(e) { // when toolbar button is clicked, open file select modal
                  inp.trigger('click');
                }
              });

              // when a file is selected, upload it to the server
              inp.on("change", function(e){
                uploadFile($(this), editor);
              });


            function uploadFile(inp, editor) {
              var input = inp.get(0);
              var data = new FormData();
              data.append('files', input.files[0]);

              $.ajax({
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/a/images',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                dataType : 'json',
                processData: false, // Don't process the files
                contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                  editor.insertContent('<img class="content-img" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}' + data.location + '" data-mce-src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}' + data.location + '" />');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  if(jqXHR.responseText) {
                    errors = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText).errors
                    alert('Error uploading image: ' + errors.join(", ") + '. Make sure the file is an image and has extension jpg/jpeg/png.');
                  }
                }
              });
            }
      }
    });


</script>
```

Here is my controller for Spring MVC and method to save files:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/a/images", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleTinyMCEUpload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile files[]) {
    System.out.println("uploading______________________________________MultipartFile " + files.length);
    String filePath = "/resources/uploads/tinyMCE/" + files[0].getOriginalFilename();
    String result = uploadFilesFromTinyMCE("tinyMCE", files, false);
    System.out.println(result);
    return "{\"location\":\"" + filePath + "\"}";

}

private String uploadFilesFromTinyMCE(String prefix, MultipartFile files[], boolean isMain) {
    System.out.println("uploading______________________________________" + prefix);
    try {
        String folder = context.getRealPath("/") + "/resources/uploads/" + prefix;
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = null;
        result.append("Uploading of File(s) ");

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (!files[i].isEmpty()) {

                try {
                    boolean created = false;

                    try {
                        File theDir = new File(folder);
                        theDir.mkdir();
                        created = true;
                    } catch (SecurityException se) {
                        se.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (created) {
                        System.out.println("DIR created");
                    }
                    String path = "";
                    path = folder + files[i].getOriginalFilename();
                    File destination = new File(path);
                    System.out.println("--> " + destination);
                    files[i].transferTo(destination);
                    result.append(files[i].getOriginalFilename() + " Succsess. ");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Product Image saving failed", e);
                }

            } else
                result.append(files[i].getOriginalFilename() + " Failed. ");

        }

        return result.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Error Occured while uploading files." + " => " + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```